# How to install OpenLDAP for windows silently

Tags: windows, openldap

I am trying to find information about running the exe installer at [OpenLDAP for Windows](http://www.userbooster.de/en/download/openldap-for-windows.aspx). The forum has little info and the installation documentation only describes the UI based install.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the exe is wrapping 2 msi files: The main installation msi and the kerberos msi.
To get them I used 7zip to extract the OpenLDAPforWindows_x64.exe installer. I then copied and renamed the folloinwg following files:

- OpenLDAPforWindows_x64\.rsrc\BIN\229 -> OpenLDAPforWindows_2.4.42_x64.msi
- OpenLDAPforWindows_x64\.rsrc\BIN\231 -> kfw-4.0.1-amd64.msi

I can then call each of them separately from the command line.

For example to call the kerberos installer with logging (allows to get the properties that can get passed to the installer when running it silently, eg: KERBEROSDIR):

```
msiexec /i kfw-4.0.1-amd64.msi /log kerberos_inst.log
```

To call the OpenLDAP installer silently while setting a custom install directory:

```
msiexec /i OpenLDAPforWindows_2.4.42_x64.msi /qn /log openldapd_inst.log INSTALLLOCATION="F:\CustomOpenLdap\"
```